# VS-2019: Debugging remotely a netcore app running on Linux, when symbols are on a network drive

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, remote-debugging, debug-symbols

If I deploy a netcore app on Linux and I include the symbols (files .pdb) on same path, I may attach remotely VS2019 and debug without any problem.
If a publish the symbols on a network drive and I set on VS2019 the path as explained at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019 , visual studio is not loading the symbols from this network path.
As far as I understand, when we debug remotely, it is actually running a debugger on Linux and VS is just a front-end. So maybe I should set the network path, where symbols are located, somewhere on Linux? Is it possible that this scenario is not supported at all, and when debugging remotely, the symbols need to be on the same server/path running the netcore app?